# how only loop rows and not table in MUIdatatble ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

i want to show data on table using API, and data from API is looping. but i want only the row of table looping and not the table. if i have 10 data in result JSON and it wil show 10 table, but i want is only show 1 table with 10 rows

my code until now data can show but its loop the table also.
Can anyone help me to loop only the row of table?

here's my code :

App.js

```
                  import React from "react";
                  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
                  import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
                  import axios from "axios";
                  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

                  class App extends React.Component {
                    constructor(props) {
                      super(props);
                    this.state = {
                      data: [],
                      errors: null,
                      isLoading: true
                    };
                  }

                  getData = async () => {
                    const option = {
                      url: "api/url",
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                      },
                      data: {
                        "data": {
                          "data" :".."
                        },
                        "encrypt": 0
                      }
                    };
                    axios(option)
                      .then(response => {
                        this.setState({
                          data: response.data.data,
                          isLoading: false,
                        });
                        console.log(response.data);

                      })
                      // If we catch any errors connecting, let's update accordingly
                      .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response);
                        this.setState({ error, isLoading: false })
                      }
                      );
                  }

                  componentDidMount() {
                    this.getData();
                  }


                    render() {
                      const { isLoading, data } = this.state;

                      const columns = ["ID","Name];

                      const options = {
                        filterType: "dropdown",
                        responsive: "scroll",
                        selectableRows:false
                      };

                      return (
                        <div>
                        <center><h3>Data</h3></center><br/>

                        {!isLoading ? (
                        data.map(post => {
                          const { id, name} = post;

                          const datatable= [
                            [
                              [id],
                              [name]
                            ]
                          ];

                        return (
                          <MUIDataTable
                          data={datatable}
                          columns={columns}
                          options={options} 
                        />

                       );

                    })
                    ) : (
                      <p>Loading...</p>
                    )}
                      </div>
                      );

                    }
                  }

                  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
                  export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't iterate thru your api response data and render `MUIDataTable`. Instead before setting the state(`data`), manipulate the data the way the muitable needs.

```js
axios(option)
    .then(response => {
        const tableData = response.data.data.map(post => {
            const {id, name} = post;
            return [id, name];
        }
        this.setState({
            data: tableData,
            isLoading: false,
        });
        console.log(response.data);

    })
```

Then render the table like this:

```js
...
return (
                        <div>
                        <center><h3>Data</h3></center><br/>

                        {!isLoading ? (
                          <MUIDataTable
                          data={this.state.data}
                          columns={columns}
                          options={options} 
                        />)
                    : (
                      <p>Loading...</p>
                    )}
                      </div>
                      );

                    }
...
```